# Python: Networkx get path between given two nodes with nodes and edges

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

Is there any function to get the list of all paths which will consist of nodes and the edges between any two given nodes from a graph?

Functions like `dijkstra_path()` and `shortest_path()` etc return only nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [get_edge_data()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.get_edge_data.html) function. Check the page for examples how to use it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i stored nodes in a dictionary using all_simple_paths() function then iterated over pairs to get edge data using get_edge_data() function.